# Send json as request body or POST json in a variable

Tags: php

I am trying to figure out, is there any way of sending raw json to php instead of POST parameter. If it is possible then which way is best i mean either request body or POST parameter.

Comment: Why don't you want to use the POST? It is the standard way of 'posting' data to a HTTP resource

Comment: Yes, it's possible to send an HTTP request which as its request body contains raw JSON.

Comment: OK thanks, then how should i get that passed json in php script.

Comment: POST parameters *are* the request body (for POST requests, obviously.)

Comment: you can check this (using php and jquery)
link: - http://christophercasper.com/2011/10/posting-json-with-jquery-and-php/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Send an HTTP request which has a JSON string as its request body (here: using `curl` on the command line):

```
$ curl -d '{"foo":"bar"}' example.com/test.php
```

Read this request body in PHP:

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

Decode it:

```
$data = json_decode($json, true);
```

---

PHP's `$_POST` superglobal is automatically populated as an array **if the request body of a POST request contains URL encoded key-value pairs** (e.g. `foo=bar&baz=42`). In the above example you're still using an HTTP POST request with "POST data". It just doesn't automatically end up in `$_POST` because PHP doesn't know how to decode JSON automagically.